# Corona SDK (LUA) - Trouble With Inserting Into Table

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I have searched around quite a bit and couldn't quite find a solution for this.  Any help you can offer would be appreciated.

```
-- The array compiled of enemies only allowed in the current
-- level phase
local EnemyList = {}
-- Counter to determine the next spot in the EnemyList
-- array to insert into
local counter   = 1

for i=1,#Enemies do
    if Enemies[i].phase == 0 or Enemies[i].phase == which_phase then
        EnemyList[counter].src      = Enemies[i].src
        EnemyList[counter].exp      = Enemies[i].exp
        counter                     = counter + 1
    end
end
```

I am getting an error about attempting to index a `nil` value, in reference to the `EnemyList` table/array.  What I am trying to accomplish is I am trying to compile a new array of only enemies that are allowed.  I guess I am unsure how to insert a new row into the `EnemyList` table.  I tried using `table.insert`, but the value parameter is required, and I am not sure how to do that with the fact that I am storing multiple values into the `EnemyList` array.

Any help or insight on the proper way to insert a new row into an empty table/array would be much appreciated.  Thanks!

**EDIT:**
I got a working solution, but I figured I should update the code here if anyone in the future finds it.

```
-- The array compiled of enemies only allowed in the current
-- level phase
local EnemyList = {}

for i=1,#Enemies do
    if Enemies[i].phase == 0 or Enemies[i].phase == which_phase then
        table.insert( EnemyList, { src = Enemies[i].src, exp = Enemies[i].exp } )
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store tables within tables in Lua. Tables are indexed in one of two ways: First, by index number. This is what `table.insert` uses; it will add an entry at the next index number.

The second way is by key; e.g.

```
> t = {}
> t.test = {}
> =t.test
table: 0077D320
```

You can insert tables into tables; this is how you create a 2D table. Because of the way you've defined your tables, `type(EnemyList[counter]) = table`.

You can insert new entries into tables by running `table.insert(table, value)`. This will assign `value` to the next available numeric entry. `type(value)` can also be a `table`; this is how you create "multidimensional arrays" in Lua.

As an aside, instead of using `for i=1,#Enemies` I would suggest using `for i,v in ipairs(Enemies)`. The second one will iterate over all numerical entries in the `Enemies` table.

Comment: I really appreciate your response, but I am having trouble fully understanding how to implement it in my situation.  Is there any chance you can give me an example of what the table.insert() code would look like relative to my example?  I will tinker on my own, but if you could offer further guidance, I would be super appreciative.

Comment: So I ended up tinkering and getting it working the way you suggested:

table.insert( EnemyList, { src = Enemies[i].src, exp = Enemies[i].exp } )

Comment: @JoshWa Awesome! If you'd like further reading, I suggest going through [this](http://lua-users.org/wiki/TablesTutorial) in detail.

Comment: Thank you for the link and the help!  Now to research ipairs, because I don't quite get the suggestion about changing my loop :)  I would upvote the answer, but I don't have enough rep :(

Comment: @JoshWa I rarely ever use variable increments. `ipairs` and `pairs` are extremely useful tools. Let me know if you have questions!

Comment: I have never heard of ipairs and pairs before.  Is there any chance you can give me an example of how it would be used in my context?  That way, I can get a good idea of what it looks like and why it is beneficial?  Thanks again for the continued help.

Comment: Try the following: `t = {1,1,2,3,5}`, `for i,v in ipairs(t) do print(i,v) end`

Comment: @Tethien - wow, I understand how that works now!  That is actually a really amazing tool to use.  Thank you for bringing this to my attention in the first place, and then further for helping me along the way with my questions.